# How can I append dictionary to a key of mother dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm try to append a new dictionary to a key of dictionary but it fails with an [error like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdzXm.png)

My code:

```
dict={'a':{1:"1"},'b':{2:'2'}}
print(dict)
dict['a'].append({3:'3'})
print(dict)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please include your code and full error stack trace as [formatted text](/help/formatting) instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dictionary contains other dictionaries.

Just set the key of the inner dictionary:

```
dict['a'][3] ='3'
print(dict)
```

Output

```
{'a': {1: '1', 3: '3'}, 'b': {2: '2'}}
```

As a side note, don't use `dict` as a variable name. It is a type in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary does not have an append method. You can simply add a key-value pair `D[key]=value` if the `key` exists, the `value` will get replaced if now new key-value pair get added.

Solution will be as follows:

```
dict={'a':{1:"1"},'b':{2:'2'}}
a = dict['a']
a[3]='3'
dict['a']=a
print(dict)
```